# Check if a date exists in a string, and if so, remove it

Tags: python, regex

How can I check if a string contains a date in the format YYYY-MM-DD, and if it does, strip it out?

```
text = '2014-06-25 Testing 12345'
text = removeDate(text)
print(text)

>> 'Testing 12345'
```

Comment: by using regular expression if a date format is known?

Comment: Do you also want to check the validity of the date. That is, the date is correct or not (like, 2013-25-26) and if not then do not process it?

Comment: yes, ideally id like to check the validity of the date as well

Answer (score 4):

By using regular expression, assuming the date format will always be `YYYY-MM-DD`:

```
import re

text = '2014-06-25 Testing 12345'
text = re.sub('\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}', '', text).strip()
print (text)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
import re
def removeDate( text ):
    return re.sub( '\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d ?', '', text )
```

This removes any sequence of 4 digits, dash, 2 digits, dash, 2 digits, and optional space with "".

Answer (score 1):

You can check with regex;

```
re.match('(\d{4})[/.-](\d{2})[/.-](\d{2})$', text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a regex for a date format http://www.regular-expressions.info/dates.html, and once you have found the string/portion of the string, you can replace that in python itself http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm

Answer (score 0):

If your string contains date as YYYY-MM-DD or YYYY.MM.DD, this will take it out and give you the remaining.

```
import re
def date_elimination(text):
    date_pattern = re.search("(\d{4}[-.]+\d{2}[-.]+\d{2})", text)
    if date_pattern is not None and date_pattern != 'None':
        text = re.sub('(\d{4}[-.]+\d{2}[-.]+\d{2})', '', text)
        return text.strip()
    else:
        return text.strip()
test = "2014-06-25 Testing 12345"
print date_elimination(test)
```